# How to use the text visualizer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I have found this link that introduces the usage of Text Visualizer.

http://saraford.net/2008/09/23/did-you-know-how-to-use-the-text-visualizer-319/

Also, I have used the following code snippet in order to trigger the text visualizer in VS2010 SP1.

```
string str = "Hello World";
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

When I hover the mouse on top of str, I only see "(local variable) string str" without seeing the exptected "Text Visualizer/XML Visualizer/HTML Visualizer". Do I miss something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visualisers are a feature of the Visual Studio Debugger, i.e. they're a runtime feature.

Set a breakpoint, run your program and hover the mouse over the variable name:

[image: Screenshot]

At design-time, Visual Studio shows only the type of the variable:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Put some XML content inside your string and try again.

Answer (score 0):

At what point are you setting the breakpoint?  If you're on the first line (string str=) then there isn't a value for str yet.

Set the breakpoint on the second line, then mouse over str.